# Best practices for handling large number of images in android

Tags: android, image, performance

I am loading 150 images into 2 different layout (a custom grid layout and custom linear layout) in a native android app (it's like a gallery: same 150 images in each view but different sizes - I need to do this so I can switch really fast to specific indices in either view).

There are 2 kinds of constraints:
1. Loading this the first time over the network reliably (after which it is cached locally) and dealing with potential network failure in the midst of transfer. Images are already as compressed as they can be while remaining readable.
They are loaded in async, and if there is a disruption, it tried to update from the server any image that is not available locally. Yet there is a fair bit of lag when this happens.

1. Memory issues due to the large number of images loaded into memory. The app is becoming a bit slow after a threshold number of images.

I am reusing views (when the image set is changed), and deferring things like reading bitmap away from the UI thread. Are there other best practices I ought to follow in this kind of an app?

Comment: try [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) image loader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Android-Universal-Image-Loader (https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for handling large number of images. This library properly handled caching of images and memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

It should go without saying, but download the smallest images you can stand for those places they're being displayed, in terms of dimensions and filesize.  Playing with compression levels can help with the latter.

Another hacky solution is to compose the grid of images server-side and simply send the single result image to the device.  The benefits of this would diminish if the images vary by user, and vary each time they open the app.

Answer (score 0):

do not load full layout at the same time. Use method called getView, it is called then separate View is appeared on screen. You need to override this method.